# Hide an element loaded from external url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide all table rows that don't contain the string "Marc" from a js widget loaded from an external url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  id = "ki1120mmvd";
  name = "schedules";
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

I've been able to hide some elements within the table rows with css using the class id or attribute but it looks like I need js/jquery/php to completely eliminate the rows and everything I've found hasn't worked.

Here is a link to where I grabbed the code:
http://www.funkydoor.com/studio_polk_street.html

Here is how I'm using it: 
http://www.marcmatisyoga.com/schedule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:contains` selector is the perfect choice. But, in your specific case, there is some more effort to be done in order to make it work. In my tests, it seems that due to some broken URL's in the external script that are loaded dynamically, `jQuery` or `$` are `undefined`. The workaround is to reload the `jQuery` API after the table (and the other external scripts) loads.

**[UPDATE]**

I'm re-posting the whole content of a `.html` file which I believe it renders the correct structure (for me, it works in Chrome). There are still some necessary modifications you'll have to do in order to achieve your desired font color and URL formatting, which you can implement by `jQuery`'s `.css()` function, as I did below. Please note that:

1. I removed entirely the `<style>...</style>` tag and
2. I'm calling the `waitForFnc` function in the `<body>`'s `<script>` tag, just after the external script is loaded dynamically.

I apologize for the need of horizontal scrolling to see the full `jQuery` style formatting, but it's not really relevant to the solution up to the point when you would like to modify it apply your own formatting.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
            var count=0;

            function waitForFnc(){
                if(typeof $ != "undefined")
                {
                    if($("tr.bikram_yoga").length==0){
                       window.setTimeout(waitForFnc,50);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $(" div.healcode .header, div.healcode table.schedule tr th, div.healcode table.schedule tr.odd td, div.healcode table.schedule tr.even td").css("background-color","#f4f4f4");
                            $(".location, span.print_text, a.print_version, .mbo_class, span.day_links, .header, span.hc_date_year, div:nth-of-type(10), a[href*='100000210'], a[href*='/13/'], a[href*='100000242'], a[href*='100000201'], a[href*='/142/'], a[href*='100000174'], a[href*='100000229'], a[href*='100000053'],th.trainer").hide();
                            $("div.healcode").css("padding","20px 0 0 20px !important");
                            $("div.healcode span.hc_day").css({"margin-left": "0 !important",
            "text-align": "left !important"});
                            $("div.healcode table.schedule").css("border","none !important");
                            $("table .schedule, tr schedule_header th").css("background-color","#f4f4f4");
                            $("tr.bikram_yoga").not(":contains('Marc')").hide();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(count==0){
                        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
                        var oScript= document.createElement("script");
                        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
                        oScript.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
                        oHead.appendChild( oScript);
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                    window.setTimeout(waitForFnc,50);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                <div style="background-color: white;">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    id = "ki1120mmvd";
                    name = "schedules";
                    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://healcode.com/javascripts/hc_widget.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
                    waitForFnc();
                </script>
                <noscript class="normal_left_yellow">
                    Please enable Javascript in order to view the class schedule: <a href="http://healcode.com" target="_blank">HealCode</a>
                </noscript>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm actively pursuing your approach. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eldereko/ULvAv/6/) I changed the class from .schedule to .bikram_yoga so it targets that specific element without success. If possible could you take a look and see if I'm missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: Yowza! Thank you very much. I'm currently going through the Code Academy tutorials and the fact that it's possible to manipulate code from an external URL is amazing. The fact that you took time to help a  total stranger is life affirming.

Comment: P.S. I think I've reached a skill level where I can help others with more basic html and css questions stack overflow. If I can make someone else feel as good as I do right now due to the help of someone else it's totally worth it.

Comment: I'm new on stack overflow and haven't reached a rep of 15 yet but will definitely give an up vote when I reach that threshold. Is there anything else I could do in the meantime?

Comment: Well, I saw you marked @Stokedout's solution as an answer, I was wondering if I will get some rep through an up vote for my contribution. Since you changed that, I am satisfied at the moment :) Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery selector and then hide the information based on that.

```
  $("div").not(":contains('marc')").hide();
```

[Quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NxVmh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this client side then try JQuery. You can use the `$.each` method to iterate over every element and remove those not containing "Marc"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.schedule tr').each(function(index){
         if ($(this).html().indexOf('Marc') === -1)
             $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion using the .bikram_yoga class without success.

Comment: @eldereko it does work. See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/stokedout/TCYsU/)

Comment: Maybe it's because you are loading the content externally so the above code might execute before your html is retrieved, thus ignoring the hiding of elements? @Alex Filipovici has addressed this in his solution below with setTimeout

Comment: Sorry Stokedout, I meant to delete that comment. It was poorly thought out. Currently learning Javascript and Jquery and your feedback helped in the general sense of what is possible. @Alex use of setTimeout was the crucial element of dealing with affecting code from an external URL.