# Hide an element loaded from external url via widget

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm setting up a website for my brother in-law. Been using a few services that are pretty inescapable in his industry. I could vent right now about them -- but I won't.

I'd like to remove the "Powered by" logo that appears on the schedule and the links:

[image: screenshot]

This is a link to the site: http://goo.gl/lHv7dF (using a shortener in case I have to remove it for some reason).

I had found this question previously asked on stack-flow in regards to the same conundrum. It has some dead links, and sort of comes in the middle, and relates to code found on a defunct webpage.  [Hide an element loaded from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212816/hide-an-element-loaded-from-external-url)

I want to point out that these plugins aren't free at all. They're amazingly pricey. It's kind of gross that the logo remains.

I appreciate your help!

**TL;DR:** Need to stop a specific element from displaying on a WP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

*I do not give my opinion on the fact of hiding the logo or not, that's your business, but be sure you have the right.*

You should add this CSS rule in your style.css file (or into your WP template settings page if there is a field like "write your own css here") :

```
.hc_footer img { display:none; }
```

The rule hides all the image elements which are on the footer of the timetable. Currently there is only the "powered-by" logo so it's OK.

Comment: That was a totally brilliant call. I was certain it would work. I added that CSS using my theme options and.... still there. http://goo.gl/6DtMvo. Also, on this page, when you click "Buy Now" .... iframe. http://goo.gl/b5oDQN. Did I apply the CSS wrong? I'm seeing a ton of stylesheets. I disabled cache'ing for the time being. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You apply the CSS right... but I don't see the logo anymore (and I don't see the hc_footer div neither in the sourcecode). Did you find another workaround ?

Comment: Yeah -- Paying them $5 a month to remove the branding. Jerks. I appreciate the effort though!